# Querying items between a range of dates using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get my query working correctly. It's supposed to return 5 items which have a `utcTime` that falls between two dates. I've verified that documents in my mongoDB do have correct dates and should be returned. This query works if I remove the `.where` line. In fact it works if I remove the `gte` and `lt` lines. The date gets parsed correctly so I'm not sure why this query is failing me.

I've also tried the alternative which is to put a filter in the `find` function like this

```
{
  "utcTime": {
      "$gte": new Date(req.params.startdate),
      "$lt": new Date(req.params.enddate)
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work either.

```
// Get the top 5 items sorted in decreasing order by karma in between
// the specified dates
listItemRoute.route('/top5/:startdate/:enddate').get((req, res) => {

  console.log(req.params.startdate) //2020-05-13T07:00:00Z
  console.log(req.params.enddate)   //2020-05-20T07:00:00Z

  ListItem
    .find()
    .limit(5)
    .where('utcTime').gte( new Date(req.params.startdate) ).lt( new Date(req.params.enddate) )
    .sort({karma: -1})
    .exec((error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error)
      } else {
        res.json(data)
      }
    })
})
```

Here's my model

```
// Define collection and schema
let ListItemSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   karma: {
      type: Number
   },
   utcTime: {
      type: Date
   }
})
```

Everything looks correct and I've tried many other stackoverflow suggestions to no avail. Any help would be awesome.

Edit: example of DB data

```
{
    "name": "TITLE BLAH",
    "karma": 11502,
    "utcTime": "2020-05-17T09:50:21Z"
}
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Sure thing. I've updated the post

Comment: The date in DB should be in this format `ISODate("2020-05-17T09:50:21Z")` for the query to work. Can you please check the format in DB

Comment: Thank you Vishnu. That was my problem. I was storing it as a string even though in the model I changed it to a `Date`. Feel free to post an answer so I can give you the answer.